# How to use if constexpr in template fold expressions?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, fold-expression

I would like to write a sum function with variable number of argument with the condition that it should ignore argument that are not `std::is_arithmetic`

I have figured out a recursive version that works

```
auto old_sum(){
    return 0;
}

template<typename T1, typename... T>
auto old_sum(T1 s, T... ts){
    if constexpr(std::is_arithmetic_v<T1>)
        return s + old_sum(ts...);
    else
        return old_sum(ts...);
}
```

I am wondering if I can use the `if constexpr` in the context of fold expression to make the following code only considers arithmetic types from the argument pack:

```
template<typename... T>
auto fold_sum(T... s){
    return (... + s);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As we do not have a ternary `constexpr` operator, we can use a lambda instead.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename... T>
constexpr auto fold_sum(T... s){
    return (... + [](auto x)
    {
        if constexpr(std::is_arithmetic_v<T>) return x;
        else return 0;
    }(s));
}
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    static_assert(fold_sum(0, nullptr, 5, nullptr, 11, nullptr) == 16);
}
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/SAWRbB)

Comment: You should give the fold the identity of the sum to handle empty pack.

Comment: Would be quite a bit easier to read if you named the lambda ;-)

Comment: Is the `else` really necessary here? I can't imagine `if constexpr` would allow for a way to write unreachable code if intentionally misused.

Comment: Yes `else` is necessary. This is a limitation of `if constexpr`. The alternative branch must be explicitly marked by `else` to force ignoring the invalid branch completely. It is not a big deal in most cases because the compiler will be able to optimize out the unless branch, but it would avoid triggering compilation failure if one of the branch does not make sense at compile-time, ie `if constexpr (!std::is_same_v<T, std::string>) return x else return x.c_str();`. Here, compilation would fail without explicit `else` directive if `c_str` is not defined no matter if the condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 4):

You absolutely want to use `if constexpr`?

I propose a different alternative: `std::get()` and `std::pair` to simulate a `constexpr` ternary operator as follows (with a Vittorio Romeo's improvement; thanks)

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename ... Ts>
constexpr auto fold_sum (Ts const & ... s)
 { return (... + std::get<std::is_arithmetic_v<Ts>>(std::pair{0, s})); }

int main ()
 {
   static_assert(fold_sum(0, nullptr, 5, nullptr, 11, nullptr) == 16);
 }
```

Comment: Can simplify to `std::pair(0, s)` by relying on CTAD.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo - Good idea; I'm still not used to C++17 argument deduction. Thanks.